# How do I find the shortest distance between L1 and L2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Find the shortest distance between the lines
>
> $L1: x = 1 + 2t, y = 3 - 4t, z = 2 + t$
>
> L2: the intersection of the planes $x + y + z =1$  and  $2x +y - 3z = 10$

Is there a formula for this? What is the method for solving this? I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: I haven't learned this but it is on my study guide, I learned how to tell if two lines are parallel, perpendicular, skew, or intersecting. However I'm not sure that is useful here.

Comment: @asdfghjkl Have you already studied some differential calculus? Because you could attack this problem that way...

Comment: No I haven't, currently in calculus 3 which is multivariable calculus.

Comment: Well, "currently in Multivariable calculus " is waaaay after differential calculus, which in many places is studied even in high school...

Comment: Oh my campus is weird. In mine differential calculus is after multivariable calc, it goes like this: Single Variable Calculus and Analytical Geometry I, Single Variable Calculus and Analytical Geometry II, Multi Variable Calculus,  Differential Equations with Linear Algebra

Comment: Single variable calculus **must** include differential and integral calculus, otherwise what you guys do there?? Perhaps you're confusingh "differential calculus" with "differential equations"?

Comment: Oh yeah I am confusing them, lol. Yeah I learned a lot about derivatives,integrals,limits, and series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the given vector onto the unique (up to scaling) line perpendicular to both planes, this will be the shortest distance. 
$$
n_1=(1,1,1)\\
n_2=(2,1,-3)\\
\Rightarrow n_1\times n_2=(-4,5,-1)
$$
Then the shortest distance is $|(2,-4,1)\cdot(-4,5,-1)|=|-8-20-1|=29$

Answer (score 0):

ok i will start with the two planes:
multiplying the first one by 3 and adding to the second one we get
$$5x=13-4y$$ or $$x=\frac{13}{5}-\frac{4}{5}t$$ with $$y=t$$ after some algebra we get
$$z=-\frac{8}{5}-\frac{1}{5}t$$
can you proceed?